# Average Distance (Calc 3)

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is find the average distance from the origin for all points $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy the inequality: $$2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 <= 21^2$$

From my understanding we are going to use spherical coordinates but I am not to sure what to do for $\phi$.

For $\theta$ I got $$0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$$ and for $\rho$ I got $$0 \le \rho \le \frac{21}{\sqrt{2}}$$

I know that for the average distance, you want to take the integral of that equation divided by the volume of a sphere, $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$\phi$ is (loosely) defined as the angle between a ray originating from the center of the sphere and the positive $z$-axis.

If you were attempting to take the integral of the entire sphere, your limits of integration for $d\phi$ would be from $0$ to $\pi$, as an angle of $\pi$ would point in the negative $z$ direction.

Comment: I mean I am not to sure what else I could do from the information given.

Comment: Your limits of integration for $d\theta$ and $d\rho$ are correct, and I gave you the limits of integration for $d\phi$. Simply set up the triple integral, and solve. Don't forget to convert your equation to spherical coordinates.

Comment: Oh could you explain what you meant it would point in the negative z direction?

Comment: Consider a sphere centered about the origin. $\phi$ is the angle between an imaginary ray with its beginning at the origin, and the positive $z$-axis. So, if our imaginary ray is pointing straight up and is parallel to the $z$-axis, then we have an angle $\phi$ of $0$. Now imagine that we begin to let the head of that arrow fall. As the arrow falls, the angle between it and the positive $z$-axis is increasing. When the arrow is pointing straight down, it will be pointing in the negative $z$ direction, and an angle of $\pi$ will have been swept out by the ray.

Comment: I got the answer to be 3 * (21/sqrt2)^2